Schrödinger equation and Hamiltonian ground state
Is it true that the Hamiltonian flow on the state space of a quantum system "pushes" quantum states towards a ground state? In mathematical therms, given a Hamiltonian $H$, an initial state $\left\vert \psi (0) \right\rangle$, is it true that there exists a small timestep $t \geq 0$ such that $\left\langle \psi(t) \vert H \vert \psi(t) \right\rangle \leq \left\langle \psi(0) \vert H \vert \psi(0) \right\rangle$?
The reason for this question is the following (all these notions are still a little fuzzy in my head so I'll try my best to make sense). As I understand:

quantum simulation (also called Hamiltonian simulation) helps to "numerically integrate" the Schrödinger equation, i.e. construct the unitary $e^{- i H t}$, for some $t$, to obtain $\left\vert \psi (t) \right\rangle = e^{- i H t} \left\vert \psi (0) \right\rangle$;
on the other hand, finding a ground state for a Hamiltonian is a recurrent problem in quantum computing.

My question is thus: how is quantum simulation helpful in finding a ground state?
I hope all of this made sense to you, and I especially hope that my three questions are actually the same question.
Edit: So following the explanation of DaftWullie, I understand that $\left\langle \psi(t) \vert H \vert \psi(t) \right\rangle = \left\langle \psi(0) \vert H \vert \psi(0) \right\rangle$. This leaves only my last question open: how is quantum simulation helpful in finding a ground state?

Please focus your question, rather than appending edits at the bottom.

The usual method for obtaining the ground state from hamiltonian simulation is using the Phase Estimation algorithm.
If you have
$$|\psi\rangle = \sum_n{\alpha_n|\psi_{\lambda_n}\rangle}$$
Then after a Phase Estimation to the unitary $U=e^{2\pi iH}$ you get approximately(assuming it is performed with high resolution):
$$|\psi\rangle|0\rangle \rightarrow_{QPE}\sum_n{\alpha_n|\psi_{\lambda_n}\rangle|\lambda_n\rangle}$$
where $\lambda_n$ is a binary representation of the eigenvalues of $H$.
Now you get that the probability to measure a certain eigenvalue is $$P(\lambda_i) = |\alpha_i| ^2$$
The catch is that you want to prepare your initial state $|\psi\rangle$ with enough overlap with the ground state so you have enough probability to sample it after the Phase Estimation.
Of course, in order to perform the phase estimation you need to be able to simulate the hamiltonian, as this is the definition of $U$.
To see a practical implementation of this method, I refer you to the following notebook:

Applying the method to find ground state of a molecule: https://github.com/Classiq/classiq-library/blob/main/applications/chemistry/qpe_for_molecules/qpe_for_molecules.ipynb
Applying the method to find matrix eigenvalues: https://github.com/Classiq/classiq-library/blob/main/algorithms/qpe/qpe_for_matrix/qpe_for_matrix.ipynb

(Disclaimer - I am a Classiq employee and I referred to examples in Classiq)

I don't think all 3 questions are the same question. So, let me just answer one of them.
Let the eigenstates of $H$ be $|\lambda_n\rangle$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_n$. I'm going to assume that $H$ is constant in time. You can decompose your initial state as
$$
|\psi(0)\rangle=\sum_n\alpha_n|\lambda_n\rangle
$$
such that
$$
\langle\psi(0)|H|\psi(0)\rangle=\sum_n|\alpha_n|^2\lambda_n.
$$
Now, we also know that the evolution is
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle=e^{-iHt}|\psi(0)\rangle=\sum_n\alpha_ne^{-i\lambda_nt}|\lambda+n\rangle
$$
such that
$$
\langle\psi(t)|H|\psi(t)\rangle=\sum_n|\alpha_n|^2\lambda_n.
$$
The expectation of the energy does not change. It does not drive you to the ground state.
So, to answer your first question, i is technically true that there exists a t such that
$$
\langle\psi(t)|H|\psi(t)\rangle\leq\langle\psi(0)|H|\psi(0)\rangle
$$
but only because
$$
\langle\psi(t)|H|\psi(t)\rangle=\langle\psi(0)|H|\psi(0)\rangle
$$
for all $t$ and this does not help you approach the ground state.

I see, the answer was actually pretty simple, thanks! So it seems the Hamiltonian flow keeps the system at the same energy level.

@cocompletehippopotamus I don't think this is generally called "flow".
